# How to run newman for postman scripts residing in a different repository in Azure Devops?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, postman, azure-pipelines, newman

I am using the Newman extension in Azure for pipeline building but it doesn't let me specify Collection File Source from another repository. How can I go about it?